# Regex optional 7 alphanumeric characters

Tags: regex

I want to match Regex for sosreport files ,which are deferent on various RHEL version:
for instance:

sosreport-servername-20161229005243-d252.tar.xz

sosreport-servername-20161227015450.tar.xz

which Regex below worked for me:

^sosreport-servername-[0-9]{14}[^tar]*.tar.\w\w\d?$

but I have encounter deferent sosreport file stature:

sosreport-servername-542046-98734e.tar.bz2

can you please help me to form new regex that will match all those patterns ?

Comment: What did you try to adjust your regex? You could use spaces to mark those lines as code to make them better readable. What do you actually want to do with those files?

Comment: `.*` surely will match all of these patterns.

Comment: `^sosreport-illin01-[0-9]{14}[^tar]*.tar.\w\w\d?$` How did this work for the 2 lines you have provided? Replace `illin01` with `servername`

Answer (score 1):

For me this regular expression is working:

```
^sosreport-servername-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*.tar.(xz|bz2)$
```

You can even change servername by `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` or `[a-zA-Z0-9-]{7}` if you now that your servername is always 7 characters length.

Comment: If this is working for you, could you accept the answer?

Comment: the following regex matching all the above patterns: